# Get playerlist from java minecraft server using java

Tags: java, minecraft

I am working on a Minecraft server sniffer to find users by username one of the first steps to do this is to get the username data to find a match

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;  
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class ph{

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    String address = "185.199.95.86";
    int port = 25565;

    InetSocketAddress host = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    socket.connect(host, port);
    System.out.println("Done!");
    System.out.println("Making streams...");
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    System.out.println("Done!");
    System.out.println("Attempting handshake... "+host.getAddress().toString());


    byte [] handshakeMessage = createHandshakeMessage(address, port);

    // C->S : Handshake State=1
    // send packet length and packet
    writeVarInt(output, handshakeMessage.length);
    output.write(handshakeMessage);

    // C->S : Request
    output.writeByte(0x01); //size is only 1
    output.writeByte(0x00); //packet id for ping


    // S->C : Response
    int size = readVarInt(input);
    int packetId = readVarInt(input);

    if (packetId == -1) {
        throw new IOException("Premature end of stream.");
    }

    if (packetId != 0x00) { //we want a status response
        throw new IOException("Invalid packetID");
    }
    int length = readVarInt(input); //length of json string

    if (length == -1) {
        throw new IOException("Premature end of stream.");
    }

    if (length == 0) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid string length.");
    }

    byte[] in = new byte[length];
    input.readFully(in);  //read json string
    String json = new String(in);

    // C->S : Ping
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    output.writeByte(0x09); //size of packet
    output.writeByte(0x01); //0x01 for ping
    output.writeLong(now); //time!?

    // S->C : Pong
    readVarInt(input);
    packetId = readVarInt(input);
    if (packetId == -1) {
        throw new IOException("Premature end of stream.");
    }

    if (packetId != 0x01) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid packetID");
    }
    long pingtime = input.readLong(); //read response


    // print out server info
    System.out.println(json);

    System.out.println("Done!");
}

public static byte [] createHandshakeMessage(String host, int port) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    DataOutputStream handshake = new DataOutputStream(buffer);
    handshake.writeByte(0x00); //packet id for handshake
    writeVarInt(handshake, 4); //protocol version
    writeString(handshake, host, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    handshake.writeShort(port); //port
    writeVarInt(handshake, 1); //state (1 for handshake)

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}

public static void writeString(DataOutputStream out, String string, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    byte [] bytes = string.getBytes(charset);
    writeVarInt(out, bytes.length);
    out.write(bytes);
}

public static void writeVarInt(DataOutputStream out, int paramInt) throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        if ((paramInt & 0xFFFFFF80) == 0) {
          out.writeByte(paramInt);
          return;
        }

        out.writeByte(paramInt & 0x7F | 0x80);
        paramInt >>>= 7;
    }
}

public static int readVarInt(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (true) {
        int k = in.readByte();
        i |= (k & 0x7F) << j++ * 7;
        if (j > 5) throw new RuntimeException("VarInt too big");
        if ((k & 0x80) != 128) break;
    }
    return i;
}
}
```

I heard that the server will send a player info packet but all i get is:

```
{"version":{"protocol":4,"name":"Arcim 1.19"},"players":{"online":5638,"max":5639,"sample":[]},"description":{"text":"            §6●§e●§6● §7§lMC§6§lHUB §7[§a1.8§7-§a1.18§7] §6●§e●§6●§r \n       §6➥ §b§lPRISON§7, §e§lSKYBLOCK§7, §a§lSURVIVAL§7!§r§r"},"favicon":"data:image/png;base64,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","modinfo":{"type":"FML","modList":[]}}
```

What do all the letters mean and is it possible to get the player list from here?

If not, how can I get the player list?

Comment: Your pastebin link is not working.

Comment: its pending moderation i will just paste it here

Comment: All the letters are the Base64 encoded server icon.

Comment: do you know how i can access the player list?

Comment: The packet response from the server listing will only offer a _sample_ of online players, often not the total and the response can be modified to not include any. Additionally, players can opt-out from being visible within the playerlist, such that even being logged in they will not show up in the tab list. Not to mention large networks have separated servers such that you would need to be in the same instance as those players. In short, this is not an approach that's feasible to locate an online player.

Comment: arent the servers all connected to a address like mc.hypixel.net
could i not ping all servers under that network?

Comment: As many have stated, big servers may not show the player list (and you can't get around it by pinging their internal servers -- they modify those as well), thus making this method useless in big servers. **However**, this will work on small servers that don't modify the response.

Comment: @caelanTheCoder_64 as someone who worked there for a few years, absolutely not. You will only ping a gateway which will handle the authentication/handshake, and then directs the actual game-level packets to a specific server instance, completely transparent to the player.

Answer (score 0):

With the server you are currently pinging, it wont work. Servers can choose to override the players they send, and it can be faked. For other servers, you can receive (a sample) of this data:
[wiki.vg](https://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#Response) (lovely for packet things) states that it will be under the sample field, where you can find some of the players on the server. For smaller servers, it may show the whole player list. Try hosting your own vanilla server to see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can't know which player is on which server without adding plugin on the server.

You can only know the amount of player, but this can be faked. Here, you ping the server and you only find everything you can find.

Comment: Indeed, some servers do remove the functionality to see players on a server, but others don't. Hovering over the player count is data sent by the server, and for vanilla servers, this is the player list.

Comment: Yes but this can be changed, so you are not sure about the player list, if they are well those players, and even if it's names, we can't know if it's really those. Also, generally it's limited to few players